# consolidate dictionary with list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm using the code below:

```
dictio = {"Jesse": 6, "Maybel": 3, "Callie": 2, "Maggie": 5}  
cargo = [[6, 3], [5, 2]]  
def transport(dictio, cargo):      
    final = [ ]    
    for i in cargo:    
        for k,v in dictio.items():  
            for x in i:  
                if x==v:  
                    final.append(k)  
                print(final)
transport(dictio, cargo)
```

My function prints all the names in a single list:

```
['Maybel', 'Jesse', 'Maggie', 'Callie']
```

But that's not as expected. What should I do to keep the names in original list format, like this?

```
[['Maybel', 'Jesse'], ['Maggie', 'Callie']]
```

Comment: Are you sure that `'Jesse'` doesn't (and shouldn't) appear before `'Maybel'`??? (since `6` appears before `3`).

Comment: hi order is not important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating the appropriate sublists:

```
dictio = {"Jesse": 6, "Maybel": 3, "Callie": 2, "Maggie": 5}
cargo = [[6, 3], [5, 2]]

final = []
for i in cargo:
    sub = []
    final.append(sub)
    for k, v in dictio.items():
        for x in i:
            if x == v:
                sub.append(k)
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['Jesse', 'Maybel'], ['Maggie', 'Callie']]
```